# Access rules between two Docker networks

Tags: docker

I want to know how a container from network A can access a container in network B.

Both Docker networks are on the same Docker host.

I didn’t find this answer anywhere.
Also I tried to play with the iptables rules without success.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect containers to multiple networks, but you need to `create` them, then connect the networks, and then `start` them - the `run` command doesn't let you specify multiple networks.

Example - create two networks:

```
docker network create net-1
docker network create net-2
```

Now create two containers, intially connecting them to different networks (this image is just ubuntu with tools like `ping` installed):

```
> docker create --name ub1 --network net-1 sixeyed/ubuntu-with-utils sleep infinity
6bdf4f41d8484516e329e572356f1770ba3da5062bf5ab6fc584db294ef13865
> docker create --name ub2 --network net-2 sixeyed/ubuntu-with-utils sleep infinity
8424d296104e082e1d0bc1468332b3143459cba9bdeeb21d320709d51048e14d
```

Once created (they're not running yet), you can connect them to the other networks:

```
> docker network connect net-2 ub1
> docker network connect net-1 ub2
```

And then start them:

```
> docker start ub1
ub1                                                                                                       
> docker start ub2
ub2
```

Now the containers can access each other by name:

```
> docker exec -it ub1 ping -c 1 ub2
PING ub2 (172.19.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ub2.net-1 (172.19.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms

> docker exec -it ub2 ping -c 1 ub1
PING ub1 (172.19.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ub1.net-1 (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms
```

You can do the same with Compose, specifying multiple networks for the services.

Comment: Yup. Compose makes this a lot less annoying, too.

Comment: I'm sorry Elton, I don't want to connect two net to a containers, I want that each container will have a single net (nic) and the two containers can communicate to each other even if they are in  two different.

Answer (score 0):

If you need access from one container to another on the same host, that is easy to get by using the `--link` option of Docker in the `docker run` command or your docker-compose.yml file.

It will allow each container to see the other and reference it by its name (as if you added a custom entry in **/etc/hosts**).

For example: `docker run -d --link container1:container1 --name container2 image2:latest`

This will allow you to access container1 in container2 by its name (like running `ping container1` in container2).

See [communication-across-links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links) in the Docker documentation.